# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 IIS 7.0 and 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, asp.net-ajax

Asp.net 3.5
IIS 7
NHibernet
www.sample.com
Website hosted in a Virtual Directory

Its generate url like "/sample/home/index" instead of "/home/index"

well, the application is working with above url but when i call any Ajax data like casecade dropdwonlist, i return 404.

Actions are working fine but only When i return Json(data) it return 404.
I tried with both GET and POST

Code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSubCategories2(int id)
    {
        var data = from subCat in CategoryService.GetChildByParentCategory(
            CategoryService.GetCategoryByID(id))
                   select new { Value = subCat.ID, Text = subCat.CategoryName };

        return Json(data);
    }
```

I have one security filter & Error Handler

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method
    , Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class HandelRecordNotFound : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception.Message.IndexOf("No row with the given identifier exists") > -1)
        {
            //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Admin/InvalidRequestOrRecordNotFound");
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Admin/InvalidRequestOrRecordNotFound");
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }

        if (filterContext.Exception.Message.IndexOf("The DELETE statement conflicted") > -1)
        {
            //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Admin/InvalidRequestOrRecordNotFound");
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Admin/InvalidRequestOrRecordNotFound");
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        //filterContext.Exception.Message 

    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method
    , Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AdminAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        object userTypeObject = httpContext.Session["UserType"];

        if (userTypeObject == null ||
            (UserTypes)Enum.ToObject(typeof(UserTypes), userTypeObject) != UserTypes.Administrator)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Except above every thing is normal.

all work fine on client side but on server JsonResult method return error 404.

Answer (score 2):

First remark about your action filter: change

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Admin/InvalidRequestOrRecordNotFound");
```

to:

```
var routes = new RouteValueDictionary(
    new { controller = "admin", action = "InvalidRequestOrRecordNotFound" }
);
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routes);
```

Second remark is about the way you are calling your ajax actions. You should always use the url helpers to generate proper routes and never hardcode them in your scripts. Example:

Instead of:

```
$.get('/home/someajax', function(result) { 

});
```

Do:

```
$.get('<%= Url.Action("someajax") %>', function(result) { 

});
```

Comment: Thanks you for you answer but InvalidRequestOrRecordNotFound is a View, i am just redirecting to view. for URL, I strictly user Url.Action.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is installed in a virt folder called "sample" instead of in the site root.

Either move the app, adjust your routes or use the correct URL including the '/sample/' prefix.

Comment: No my client main website is running on root so i cannot move it to root. I usually demonstrate my work on my own domain in as sub-domain like "http://client.wayzsoft.com", in that i never found "wayzsoft" or "client" in generated Urls. Even sub-domain are also hosted as Virtual Directory, as i think. Second i have issue with JsonResult not with ActionResult and Content